# synchronous wait while file loads

Tags: c#

This is what i need to do:

1. Open file
2. File makes an API call (outside my control) that takes about 5 seconds
3. Other stuff only after step 2 is complete

My problem is managing step 2. After I open the file I need to "wait" until those 5 seconds are elapsed before proceeding with step 3. I cannot use Sleep because that blocks the whole thread. There is no asynchronous stuff, step 3 can only proceed after 2 is complete. Have searched all over, 99% of posts are about `Thread.Sleep` and `Task.Delay` async stuff.

What can I do? Timers?

Comment: Why don't you await your step 2

Comment: If I make 2 async then 3 proceeds without 2 being complete

Comment: Return a bool value from 2 by making your method async and await it in your main method that should do the trick

Comment: Can you please clarify what you expect from "synchronous wait"? `Sleep` is really the only true synchronous wait... both `Task.Delay` and timers will let your app to accept and handle messages...

Comment: @alexei I want the program to wait while the file loads without blocking the whole thread becuase if not the file won't complete the API call. I can't go to step 3 without step 2.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] demonstrating what is happening. I'm quite sure "open file" does not mean what I think it does.

Comment: Please show us the code - especially for the API call.

Answer (score 0):

> "There is no asynchronous stuff"

Why? Because you never learned what async/await means.

await localfileasync
Make api call.
Task.Delay(5000)
Step 5.

In an async method. finished.

If you can not do that... You can still work with task continuations and put a task.delay in one

> I cannot use Sleep because that blocks the whole thread.

Actually if your method is not async and CAN NOT BE ASYNC then blocking the whole thread it the only way to wait.